# Changing React App Homepage Hosted By Github

Tags: github, github-pages

So I know Github will host your public repositories, but is there anyway to change the public url without changing the repository name?

For my case I would like to change it from https://akoster15.github.io/react-portfolio to https://akoster15.github.io/akoster15

Comment: We're not GitHub support, sorry. I doubt we can give you a solution, since we cannot control the software. Potentially you could create a new page with a new name, I guess

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't exactly what you are asking for, but there is an alternative solution **without having to change the name of your repo**.

You could use [Vercel](https://vercel.com/docs/get-started) coupled with your existent GitHub repo to do things easier.

- Create an account on Vercel and link it to your GitHub account.
- Choose whichever GitHub repository you want to deploy.
- Pick the url you want your project to be shown as without needing to change anything on your repo (even **private** repos can be deployed unlike with gh-pages). Example: `https://akoster15.vercel.app/`
- Later on, if you'd decide to change the url of your project, it's as easy as adding a domain and redirecting your previous url – that you probably would have given to many people – to a new one. Like depicted on the below screenshot: [image]

Note that everything is free.